# how to pass index value of a widget to parent widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently my `contentIndex` member variable returns null in the `ResponseItem` widget and I. get an invalid argument error. It's fairly clear why this is happening.. I need the `contentIndex` variable in the `ResponseItemWidget` to be "wired" (the `contentIndex` value should mirror `contentIndex` value in the `ResponseItem` because of the for loop in the `ResponseItemWidget` ) to it's parent widget. I need to pull the index values from the child widget to the parent widget..Not sure how to do this....

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main()
{
  runApp(ResponseItem());
}

class Content{
  String body;
  String imgUrl;
  Content({this.body,this.imgUrl});

}

class Response{
  List<Content> content;

  Response(this.content);


}

class Prax{
  List<Response> responses;
  Prax(this.responses);


}


class ResponseItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Prax prax;
  final int index;
  final contentIndex;

  ResponseItem({this.prax,this.index,this.contentIndex});
  

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponseItemWidget(body: (prax.responses[index].content.isNotEmpty) ? prax.responses[index].content[contentIndex]?.body : "", 
    responseImgUrl: (prax.responses[index].content.isNotEmpty)?prax.responses[index].content[contentIndex].imgUrl:"", 
  contentLength: prax.responses[index].content.length,
  contentIndex: contentIndex);
  }
}




class ResponseItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final contentLength;
  final String body;
  final String responseImgUrl;
   int contentIndex;

  ResponseItemWidget({
    @required this.body,
    @required this.responseImgUrl,
    @required this.contentLength,
    this.contentIndex,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          for (contentIndex = 0; contentIndex <= contentLength; contentIndex++)
          ListView(children: [
            if (contentLength != 0) Text(body[contentIndex] ?? ""),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            if (contentLength != 0) Image.network(responseImgUrl[contentIndex]),
          ]),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}




//////////////////////////////
```

Comment: where's the loop?

Comment: good point!! 2 secs

Comment: what do you want to achieve by adding the loop in this place? do you want to get the index of currently viewed item?

Comment: yes... The `ResponseItemWidget` is a generic widget for other widgets. A bit of a hack for a library I'm using for graphql.

Comment: Suppose I need the the two member variables (contentIndex) for the different widgets to have the same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your entries have a predefined height, you can just use [ScrollController.position](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController/position.html) to determine which item is currently viewed.

If that's not the case, you could use a package [visibility_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector) and if one of the items becomes invisible then increment the `contentIndex`.

There's also a package called [scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) which implements the above for you.

As for setting the value itself, just pass a function to `ResponseItemWidget` of type `ValueChanged<int>` (it's equivalent to `void Function(int)`). Make the `contentIndex` `final` in don't modify it in `ResponseItemWidget`. Let the parent take care of managing state.

Example of using such function: https://www.dartpad.dev/3749e22cf82e0f1bf3f6d1901dfd3522?null_safety=true

```
    DemoChild(
      counter: counter,
      onCounterChange: (newValue) => setState(() {
        counter = newValue;
      }),
    );
```

```
class DemoChild extends StatelessWidget {
  final int counter;
  final ValueChanged<int> onCounterChange;

  const DemoChild(
      {Key? key, required this.counter, required this.onCounterChange})
      : super(key: key);
  // ...
}
```

Also, I can already see that your code won't work. I'm talking about this part:

```
  Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: [
      for (contentIndex = 0; contentIndex <= contentLength; contentIndex++)
      ListView(children: [
        if (contentLength != 0) Text(body[contentIndex] ?? ""),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        if (contentLength != 0) Image.network(responseImgUrl[contentIndex]),
      ]),
    ],
  ),
```

`Column` will overflow cause it doesn't care about scrollability, and `ListView` will cause render issues cause it gets unbounded height from the `Column`. Change it to

```
  ListView(
    children: [
      for (contentIndex = 0; contentIndex <= contentLength; contentIndex++)
        ...[
          if (contentLength != 0) Text(body[contentIndex] ?? ""),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          if (contentLength != 0) Image.network(responseImgUrl[contentIndex]),
        ]
    ],
  ),
```

And ideally (will make things easier for you to compute currently viewed item):

```
  ListView(
    children: [
      for (contentIndex = 0; contentIndex <= contentLength; contentIndex++)
        ResponseListItem(
          text: body[contentIndex] ?? "",
          imageUrl: responseImgUrl[contentIndex],
        )
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: I've updated the answer with https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list. I just want to make sure you don't miss it so please have a look as it's probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Cheers for all that.. I'm mainly concerned with updating the value .. How do I use the ValueChanged<int> ...?

Comment: it's a typealias for `void Function(int)`, just call it like any other function

Comment: call it from the parent widget?

Comment: pass the function from parent to child and call it from child when the index changes

Comment: could you give an example.. That's really what I'm asking. cheers